# How to properly use a regex statement in R's stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How would I extract a specific character, using stringr, based on a specific pattern.

For example, if I have the following coefficient in a tidy model table:

I(pmax(0, hp - 100))

I want to create two additional columns with hp and 100.

Example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(stringr)

 #pull in and gather data

mtcars1 <- as_tibble(mtcars)
mtcars1$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
#run model and produce model-summary table
model <- glm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + I(pmax(0, hp - 100)), data = mtcars1)

model_summary <- tidy(model)
```

How would I extract a specific character, using stringr, based on a specific pattern.

For example, if I have the following coefficient in a tidy model table:

I(pmax(0, hp - 100))

I want to create two additional columns with hp and 100.

I've tried the following that works (specific regex statement) on regex101.com, but not in r.

```
model_summary_hp <- model_summary %>%
  mutate(term1 = str_extract(term, regex("\I\(pmax\(0, ([a-z]+)\ - 100\)\)")),
     knot =  str_extract(term, regex("\I\(pmax\(0, [a-z]+ - ([0-9]+)\)\)")))
```

I get the following error:

`Error: '\I' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\I"`

I'm not sure why it doesn't recognize the regex statement.

Comment: Double the backslashes and do not escape word characters, only escape what should be escaped. `regex("I\\(pmax\\(0, ([a-z]+) - ([0-9]+)\\)\\)")` and use with `str_match`

Comment: all of them or certain ones?

Comment: It thinks you're trying to escape the `I`. If you want the `\ ` to show up, you need to escape it itself. So `\I` would become `\\I`

Comment: I don't.  I wan only 'hp' and '100' to show up in the two new columns

Comment: With `str_match` the first column is always the whole match. So, you will need to use columns [,2] and [,3].

Comment: Hi @@WiktorStribizew.  I'm using str_extract though.  not str_match.

Comment: Then, to extract two values, you need 2 `str_extract`  calls with specific patterns. Or, maybe even `gsub`s.

Comment: was this what you were thinking?

`model_summary_hp <- model_summary %>%
  mutate(term1 = str_match(term, regex("I\\(pmax\\(0, ([a-z]+)\\ - 100\\)\\)")),
         knot =  str_match(term, regex("I\\(pmax\\(0, [a-z]+ - ([0-9]+)\\)\\)")))`

Comment: The first can be `"(?<=I\\(pmax\\(0, )[a-z]+"` or `"(?<=I\\(pmax\\(0,\\s{0,10})[a-z]+"`. The second can be `"\\d+(?=\\)\\))"`. These are for use with `str_extract`.

Comment: With `sub`: 1) [`sub("I\\(pmax\\(\\d+,\\s*([a-z]+)\\s*-\\s*\\d+\\)\\)","\\1", term)`](https://regex101.com/r/kj0BPY/1). 2) [`sub("I\\(pmax\\(\\d+,\\s*[a-z]+\\s*-\\s*(\\d+)\\)\\)","\\1", term)`](https://regex101.com/r/kj0BPY/2).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew .  Do you want to put that in an answer for me to check?  Why does this work in R (where it matters) but is not recognized in regex101.com?

Comment: stringr uses ICU regex engine, regex101 uses PCRE, JS, Python, Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very important thing is to understand how to use a regex online tester: if you see something there, it does not mean it will work the same in your target environment. Since you are using `stringr` functions, you must make sure your patterns are ICU engine compatible while regex101 only supports PCRE, JS, Python `re` and Go regex engines. Mind that if you use `(g)sub` you must make sure the regex is compatible with the TRE regex engine or PCRE (when adding `perl=TRUE`).

Now, you need to extract 2 values, and that means you need to use 2 `str_extract` or `sub` calls.

A `stringr` approach:

```
1) "(?<=I\\(pmax\\(0, )[a-z]+"          # or
   "(?<=I\\(pmax\\(0,\\s{0,10})[a-z]+"

2) "\\d+(?=\\)\\))"
```

Here, the main points are lookarounds: `(?<=I\\(pmax\\(0, )` matches `I(pmax(0,` immediately to the left of the current location, but does not put the matched text into the match value. The `(?=\\)\\))` pattern is a positive lookahead that requires the presence of `))` immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that the second version of the first regex will not work at regex101.com since the lookbehind pattern is constrained-width here, not fixed-width.

A `sub` approach (TRE regex):

```
1) sub("I\\(pmax\\(\\d+,\\s*([a-z]+)\\s*-\\s*\\d+\\)\\)","\\1", term)

2) sub("I\\(pmax\\(\\d+,\\s*[a-z]+\\s*-\\s*(\\d+)\\)\\)","\\1", term)
```

Here, the point is to match the whole string, capture what you need, and replace with the placeholder to this group, `\1`.

Comment: One last question.  For the stringr approach, what if the the first string extracted is delimited?  what if hp was actually hp_model and I needed the whole "hp_model" extracted?

Comment: @Jordan You may match any word char with `\w+`. Replace `[a-z]+` with `\\w+`.